# Struts 1.2.9 JSP TLD Unable to load tag handler class [com.ibm.struts.tablib.logic.ForwardTag] for tag [logic:forward]

Tags: tomcat, web, struts

while I access application home page I get the issue in the subject

Struts 1.2.9 JSP TLD Unable to load tag handler class [com.ibm.struts.tablib.logic.ForwardTag] for tag [logic:forward]

am not sure if the package com.ibm.struts is from a different jar, as unable to find or something to be fixed in the application

Any guidance is much appreciated...

Comment: Environment Tomcat 9

Comment: It's certainly a different jar, and it's likely there's a typo, because I doubt they spelled `taglib` wrong IRL.

Comment: sorry for the typo that was me typing there

Comment: so which jar is that @Dave Newton?

Comment: No clue. IIRC at one point they had a rebranded Struts they used as part of their management infrastructure, but this was 10-15 years ago, so who knows. You don't provide anything anybody can use to help, so unless you include any of your own taglib declarations (you used to have to declare them explicitly) etc. you're not going to get any help.

Comment: rebranded struts ? does that mean the com.ibm.struts.tablib.logic.ForwardTag is obsolete and there are no suggestions at this point??

Comment: No clue. With zero information regarding your app I don't know what you expect.

Comment: This application was developed in websphere and now being migrated to tomcat version 9, is there any information in particular you are looking at?? can provide that information

Comment: Where you declare the taglibs. There's nothing in Struts 1 dependencies that refers to anything in IBM packages--so it's something in your app.

Comment: WEB-INF/tld/struts-logic.tld and all the other tld's

Comment: I'm referring to the `<taglib>` in your `web.xml`. If it's not in there then you'll have to un-zip all your deployables and grep. Additional information should be added to the question, by the way. Like... what libraries you're deploying in your web app, and anything you've added to the Tomcat libs as part of this move. A normal S1 app WAR file can be dropped pretty much anywhere and run, so there's something in the app.

Comment: I've commented doctype in web.xml